# Efficient remote file diff

Tags: linux, rsync, comparison

I want to verify that two large remote file systems are in sync, and if not which files are different (including if they don't exist on either side). The way I am imagining this being done is comparing checksums calculated on the respective local machines. I have tried using `rsync -cn` for this:

```
rsync -cnave "ssh -p 500" /local/path/ remoteserver:/remote/path/
```

But judging by the amount of time it's taking on just one directory I think it must be downloading the files before doing the comparison. How else can I do this? Would running the rysnc daemon on the remote server help?

Comment: Please provide the entire command line you used to invoke `rsync`.

Comment: I think i might have just underestimated how long it would take to generate the checksums.

Comment: Well, the call looks correct. Yes, checksums are rather expensive. In most cases they aren’t required though, just checking file size and date is enough. This is what `rsync` does without `-c`.

Comment: That's a good point, thank you, I got fixated on checksum.